# Concatenating html object arrays with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-object

I'm attempting to merge two arrays made up of html objects. For some reason using .concat() will not work for me.

Here's a simple pen to demonstrate the problem: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kIeyB

Note: I tried searching for something remotely similar but found nothing that answered my question.

I figure you can do this the ole fashion way using for-loops but I rather not re-invent the wheel.

```
var x = document.getElementById("hello");
var items = x.getElementsByClassName("one");
//alert(items.length);
var items2 = x.getElementsByClassName("two");
//alert(items2.length);
items = items.concat(items2);
//alert(items.length);
```

Comment: Please state the actual problem and include a valid example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The codepen clearly illustrates the issue I was having as the 6th line would results in an execution error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`items` and `items2` are `nodeList` or `HTMLCollection` objects, not arrays.  They do not contain a `.concat()` method.  They have a `.length` property and support `[x]` indexing, but they do not have the other array methods.

A common workaround to copy them into an actual array is as follows:

```
// convert both to arrays so they have the full complement of Array methods
var array1 = Array.prototype.slice.call(x.getElementsByClassName("one"), 0);
var array2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(x.getElementsByClassName("two"), 0);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! Out of curiosity, could you explain the slice.call() and what the '0' parameter is for.

Comment: @user3718546: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice.

Comment: @user3718546 - `.slice()` works with anything that has a `.length` and supports `[i]` indexing from `0` to `length - 1` (which includes a `nodeList`, and `HTMLCollection, and `arguments` object, etc...).  So, we're using the `.slice()` method from `Array.prototype` and calling that method, but passing it a `nodeList` as the object to operate on with `.call()`.  The `0` is the first argument to `.slice()` which means to start the shallow copy at the beginning.  If you read the doc for both `.slice()` and `.call()`, you will see how they work together.

Answer (score 5):

This can be also be done like this:

```
var allitems = [];
allitems = Array.prototype.concat.apply(allitems, x.getElementsByClassName("one"));
allitems = Array.prototype.concat.apply(allitems, x.getElementsByClassName("two"));
```

The `allitems` variable will be a single javascript `Array` containing all elements with class `one` & `two`.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an array.
It returns NodeList which has length property.

Answer (score 1):

What you have are HTMLCollections, which although behave like arrays, but are not arrays. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection:

> ..A collection is an object that represents a lists of DOM nodes..

In your case, you could concatenate these objects together into a new array:

```
var itemsnew;
var x = document.getElementById("hello");
var items = x.getElementsByClassName("one");
var items2 = x.getElementsByClassName("two");
itemsnew = Array.prototype.concat.call(items, items2);
```

Now, if you:

```
console.log(itemsnew);
```

Will return:

```
[HTMLCollection[1], HTMLCollection[1]]
```

And:

```
console.log(itemsnew[0][0]);
```

Will return:

```
<div class="one"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answering and everything you said was correct. For my situation; however, I was trying to concatenate multiple arrays so that I could then transverse them in one loop. Having a multi-dimensional array like you proposed wouldn't be the most appropriate and most useful approach for users trying to manipulate multiple nodeLists.